# SOAP PHP Question about is my code correct?

Tags: php, soap

I have a simple question, hope that anyone can help.

I have this code from a ?wdsl service :

```
<xsd:complexType name="LoginInfo">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="user" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Then I got this code in PHP :

```
$client = new SoapClient($enllaç.'?wsdl', $aOptions);
$param = array("password" => $password, "user" => $login);
$result = $client->login( array('LoginInfo' => array($param)));
```

Anyone can let me know if this is correct? becouse is not working. With SoapUI I can access without any problem, but using PHP no. I think that I'm loosing something.

Answer (score 0):

It will either be:

```
$client->__soapCall("LoginInfo",$param);
```

or

```
$client->LoginInfo($password, $login);
```

Depending on wether or not 'LoginInfo' is the name of the service function.

http://be.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

is a good start.

Comment: I already check that but it says: Fatal error: SOAP Fault: (faultcode: Client, faultstring: Function ("LoginInfo") is not a valid method for this service)

Comment: That means thatr LoginInfo is not a valid function, The wsdl excerpt you showed identifies a parameter to a method. Could you supply a location or larger example fo the wsdl?